# command line arguments to Android instrument test using gradle

Tags: android, automated-tests, gradle, command-line-arguments

Does anyone has an idea about how to pass command line arguments to  Android instrumentation tests run using gradle. Calling gradle connectedInstrumentTest with -p arguments or -D arguments did n't seem to work .I am trying to pass command line arguments to my instrument test using gradle.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible since 1.3.0 version of plugin according to docs: 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

> It's now possible to specify instrumentation test runner arguments in
>   build.gradle (in defaultConfig or per flavor):
>
> ```
> android {
>      defaultConfig {
>          testInstrumentationRunnerArguments size: "medium"
>      } 
>  }
> ```
>
> This can also be done on the command line:
>
> ./gradlew cC -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.size=medium

Answer (score 1):

you mean pass arguments to the am command? It's not possible at the moment.

Comment: Can we read it from a say properties file? Im looking to pass tags and not change the build.gradle everytime i run a subset of tests.