# How can I run a single android instrumentation test case?

Tags: android, junit, android-instrumentation

Not a unit test, but an instrumentation test.

My app has multiple flavors, so I run:

`./gradlew connectedClientDebugAndroidTest` to run my instrumentation tests (flavor name is **client**).

But I want to run one particular instrumentation test case class called `MyActivityTestCase.java`. Is this possible? If it is what is the command to run this

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this from the command-line. In Android Studio, you can right click on a class name and go to the Run menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [command line arguments to Android instrument test using gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797324/command-line-arguments-to-android-instrument-test-using-gradle)

Comment: Perhaps http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/05/gradle-goodness-running-single-test.html will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I fixed this was by putting the single TestCase that I want into a specific folder by **flavor**.

- So in this example, my flavor is named **client**, so I put the single test that I want to run for this flavor into `app/src/androidTestClient/MyActivityTestCase.java`
- Then run `./gradlew connectedClientDebugAndroidTest`

Not a solution if you have multiple test cases for a specific build flavor, but for me that wasn't the case so it works.

- All my other tests are in my flavor called **other**, in the folder:
  `app/src/androidTestOther/`. So to run the other instrumentation tests I just run the command `./gradlew connectedOtherDebugAndroidTest`

Answer (score 1):

With Gradle, you can run a single test by using the `test.single` system property. You set it from the command-line with the `-D` option. For example

```
$ gradle -Dtest.single=MyActivityTestCase connectedClientDebugAndroidTest
```

For more details, see http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/05/gradle-goodness-running-single-test.html.

Comment: That didn't work, it runs all tests. does it need to be the full packagename for `MyActivityTestCase` ?

Comment: Nope, full packagename runs all tests as well

Comment: yes I did. ran `./gradlew -DconnectedClientDebugAndroidTest.single= MyActivityTestCase connectedClientDebugAndroidTest` and  it ran all mytests

Comment: @Prem It appears that the link in my answer uses the `java` plugin for gradle. The `android` plugin has slightly different tasks. You will need to find the correct task to use instead of `test`. I suggest using `./gradlew tasks` to see the list of possible tasks to try.

Comment: Yes, the task is `connectedClientDebugAndroidTest`. However, running `./gradlew -DconnectedClientDebugAndroidTest.single=MyActivityTestCase connectedClientDebugAndroidTest` still results in execution of all of the testcases

Comment: Try `./gradlew -DandroidTest.single=MyActivityTestCase  connectedClientDebugAndroidTest ` or `./gradlew -DconnectedClientDebugAndroidTest.single=MyActivityTestCase`.

Comment: I am out of suggestions. Read the link I gave and work through the examples. I suggest creating the exact Java project it describes and make sure you can reproduce the behavior given in the article. This will help you better understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax using adb shell is :

```
adb shell am instrument -w <test_package_name>/<runner_class>
```

where  is the Android package name of your test application, and  is the name of the Android test runner class you are using.

More details at: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html

Comment: Of course, this assumes that you have already compiled and installed your APK file to a device. With Gradle, you get all of this with just a single command.